# alignParentBottom hides the textview

Tags: android, xml, layout, alignment, textview

The problem here is I'm trying to stick the textview to the bottom using "alignParentBottom=true" but it hides the textview. Following is the layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<Switch
    android:onClick="adjustFocus"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hhmm"
    android:id="@+id/hhmm"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Switch
    android:onClick="adjustFocus"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hr12"
    android:id="@+id/hr12"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hhmm" />

<Switch
    android:onClick="adjustFocus"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hr24"
    android:id="@+id/hr24"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hr12" />
<Switch
    android:onClick="adjustFocus"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hh_double"
    android:id="@+id/hhdbl"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hr24" />
<Switch
    android:onClick="adjustFocus"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mm_double"
    android:id="@+id/mmdbl"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hhdbl" />



<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/offset"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mmdbl"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />


 //below is the textview I'm trying to stick to the bottom
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the java code associated to the above layout xml file. It is a fragment...

```
public class myfrag extends Fragment {
TextView tv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);


return v;
}

}
```

Please help me where I'm wrong.

Comment: can you show the screenshot ?

Comment: The textview is visible in the preview but hidden while testing on a real device.. Here are the screenshots ... Preview: http://i.imgur.com/E6F5RnP.png ... On a real device: http://i.imgur.com/SBNEZ06.png ... Pls checkout both of them

Comment: so, what are the operations that you perform to the TextView programmatically in real-time ?!!

Comment: there is no problem  working fine..

Comment: I want to update it in real-time

Comment: I'm saying that your layout must working fine in real-time running, but if it doesn't work fine so you must do any operation in the TextView programmatically

Comment: the textview is not visible when the app is running on a real device

Comment: I know, just include your code of how you declare and assign it programmatically.

Comment: your `xml` is working fine the mistake you did is in java code so post your `Activity.java` code ..

Comment: I've now included the java code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: what's the theme you are using?!!

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Hey, I still couldn't get a way out. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update this TextView:**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center|bottom" />
```